# Laravel 5.5 MySQL-based "queue" locks up the database at high request-volume

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking

I'm running into a problem that's out of my depth regarding MySQL database transactions, locking, and Laravel's Eloquent ORM. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

- Laravel 5.5
- PHP 7.2.25
- MySQL 8.0.13 (InnoDB)

My (simplified) problem is this: I have a `tasks` table in my MySQL database, an endpoint to retrieve the next task, and an endpoint to mark a task as finished or inactive. The `tasks` table is meant to act as a sort of queue, allowing users to pull the next available task that no one else is currently working on (read: task is inactive). If a task was pulled but no update has been made in 3 hours, it should again be visible to the retrieval endpoint (in case a user quit the app unexpectedly, etc.).

My problem arises with the task-retrieval endpoint. I'm using `DB::transaction` and `lockForUpdate()` here to prevent concurrency issues (i.e. two users fetching the same task before it gets marked active). It works as expected when the request per second volume is relatively low, properly fetching a unique task for each request. At higher request frequency, though, the entire `tasks` table eventually locks, requests start to time out, and the database becomes unresponsive until restarted. Here's my code:

```
// Select the next task in the queue
$task = DB::transaction(
    function () {
        $t = Task::where('finished', '=', false)
            ->where(function ($q) {
                // Task must not be active for another user
                $q->where('active', '=', false)
                    ->orWhere('updated_at', '<', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)'));
            })
            // Prefer tasks that haven't been seen yet
            ->orderBy('attempts')
            ->lockForUpdate()
            ->first();

        if (null !== $t) {
            // Set the task as active and increment attempts
            $t->active = true;
            $t->attempts++;
            $t->save();
        }

        return $t;
    }
);
```

Some additional context:

- Other requests at higher frequency with similar DB reads have no issues, so the problem here is definitely related to the transaction/locking behavior, not some other system configuration (MySQL connections, PHP threads, etc.)
- The `Task` Eloquent model has standard Laravel timestamps, so `updated_at` is set automatically as a part of the `save()` method

Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or am I completely off base? Is what I'm attempting even possible, or do I need to move out of MySQL to a more traditional queuing system (Redis, SQS, etc.)? I'd have no problem switching to raw SQL queries rather than using the ORM if that would make this possible. Thanks for any and all guidance!

Comment: What engine is the table running on? If you don't know how to check you can run this in Tinker: `DB::select('show table status where name = ?',['tasks'])`

Comment: The reason I ask is that InnoDB allows you to lock one row at a time, whereas MyISAM requires you to lock the entire table.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but I think `lockForUpdate` only locks for that query, not for the `save()` query afterwards. Granted the name is quite misleading, but think it does not work the way you think it works.

Comment: @lufc It's InnoDB; I'll update the post, thanks

Comment: @PtrTon My understanding is that it read-locks the row until the DB transaction ends. It's definitely possible I'm wrong, but if so I'm not sure how to use it correctly or what the alternative would be

Comment: When it gets into that state, what does [`show engine innodb status`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-standard-monitor.html) show regarding the transactions and locks for that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this for sure but the suggestion is too long for a comment.

I think the `lockForUpdate` method may cause the row to be locked *even for consideration* during the next search. That means one search cannot complete before the previous update has been committed. (i.e. in the first search you select row A which is inactive, then in the second search you look for all inactive rows, of which row A is still one, but you can't finish the query until row A has been unlocked).

To get around this you could try adding `SKIP LOCKED` (see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)). This would exclude the locked row A from the second search and allow it to return results before the previous transaction was committed.

I cannot see a method in Laravel to add this, so you would need to add the locking clauses manually using the raw query builder or perhaps `->whereRaw` would work.

Comment: Amazing -- you're totally right. I thought the queries were running simultaneously, but your assertion was correct that each was waiting for the previous lock to release. The issue I was seeing must have been caused by reaching a query volume higher than the DB could keep up with.

The fix was also way simpler than I expected it to be: I just had to change `->lockForUpdate()` to `->lock('FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED')`. Thanks!